Layout and Widgets is disappeared when restart the engine in LyraStarterGame UE5
I've added my plugin like ShooterCore in LyraStarterGame project. Experience and HUD ActionSet i named LAS_MyGame_StandardHUD that i copied from ShooterCore are in my plugin folder. I made a new layout and widgets on my plugin. And then i changed LAS_ShooterCore_StandardHUD to LAS_MyGame_StandardHUD after set the layout and widgets. The point is i can show the layout and wigets when the game is started but if i restart the Unreal Engine, Nothing is changed but i can't see the layout and widgets. Even these don't be created. If i compile each widgets and layout, i can see the layout and widgets on the screen but the problem is still exist.
I try to add Experience folder path of my plugin into Asset Manager>Primary Asset type>LyraExperienceDefinition because i thought the problem is related with loading assets. But i can't solve the problem. Somebody help me please

Answer my self.
I have DataAsset file has same name with name of my plugin in Plugin Contents directory. The type of the DataAsset is GameFeatureData. I can add ExperienceActionSet in Asset Manager > Primary Asset Types to Scan. Here is the solution.

Add Element into Primary Asset Types to Scan.
Set values of Primary Asset type. I set it to LyraExperienceActionSet
Set values of Asset Base Class. I set it to LyraExperienceActionSet
Set Has Blueprint Class to true.
Add my Experiences directory on Directory array

